# R: Storing empty and/or multiple integer object in a data.frame like object

Tags: r, dataframe, integer, lapply

I have a collection of N integer objects:

```
a <- c(2)
b <- c(4,5,6)
c <- integer(0)
... <- c(...)
N <- c(...)
```

I want to store these along with an index / string in an object (e.g. data.frame? But I could not get a solution to work with a data.frame, I am not familiar with many object types):

```
> df
Index     Info
1         2
2         4 5 6
3         0
...       ...
N         ...
```

or

```
ID <- c("a", "b", "c")
df <- data.frame(ID)
> df
ID     Info
a         2
b         4 5 6
c         0
...       ...
N         ...
```

The goal is to create an index where I say "hey, for Index 1 / ID b, what is the Info? Oh, its 4, 5, 6. I will use these 3 numbers to access some data elsewhere."

2 additional notes:

1. It probably doesn't matter, but I am getting these integer objects from a `lapply()` or `for` loop, where each iteration would be outputting an integer object.
2. Sometimes the integer object is just `integer(0)`, so it is important to me that the object I am creating is ok with this input.

Comment: If you want to store this in a data frame you'll need to use a list column, e.g. `data.frame(Index = 1:3, Info = I(list(a, b, c)))`.

Comment: ohhhhh that `I()` function! Thats cool, thanks @RitchieSacramento

Comment: Note that tibbles have default support for list columns, but data frames need to be told to use the data as is.

Comment: I am having trouble, I do not have all the objects `a` , `b`, `c` on hand immediately, I will be inserting them into the data.frame iteratively. 

If I do:
`ID <- c("a", "b", "c")`
`df <- data.frame(ID)`
then initialize the info column:
`df$Info <- NA`
i still cant insert the objects:
`df[2,]$Info <- I(b)`
"Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Info, value = c(1, 2)) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1"

Comment: and If I try: `df$Info <- integer(0)`
this also gives me a similar error:
"Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, Info, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 3" @RitchieSacramento

Comment: Even when I try this with a tibble, I get a similar warning:
`Warning message: In tbbl$Info[1] <- b : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: `I()` is necessary during creation of the data frame, it's not needed for replacing elements.  You want a list column so you need to wrap your replacement element with `list()` not `I()`, e.g. use `df$Info[2] <- list(b)`.

Comment: Ok! Got it, sorry about that. I will go check out if using a tibble or data.frame is better for my purposes too! thanks! Got things working with the data.frame and tibble.